# Keyword based search/query in Google Drive?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Does Google Drive API support keyword searches/queries (similar to 'DocumentQuery' function available from Google Docs API)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.  See the discussion of this feature here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters